# Ошибка'0xc000007b'

Tags: c++

Мой вопрос заключается в том,что при компиляции проекта(а именно на стадии линковки программы я подключил библиотеку glew32.lib(64битную версию)),казалось что всё нормально,но когда запустил exe`шник то я получил ошибку '0xc000007b',мне интересно с чем это связано?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот здесь я подключаю зависимость (glew32.lib)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот сама ошибка при попытки запустить exe файл.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот код.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот папка с проектом.
Надеюсь кто нибудь решит мою проблему,потому-что сижу над ней уже третий день.

Comment: Убедитесь что проект тоже в 64 компилируется. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28316612/5909792

Comment: А код который у вас мы должны придумать?

Comment: @user7860670 вы не умеете текст копировать? Объясните причину по которой вы вставили код в вопрос в качестве скриншота?

Comment: @user7860670 извиняюсь, не того юзера выбрал)

Comment: Библиотеки для линковки, нужно добавлять через `L`, если собирается с помощью g++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идём в директорию include пакета вашего компилятора, запускаем поиск файла с текстом "c000007b". Поиск выдаст файл ntstatus.h, а в нём строку:

```
#define STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT ((NTSTATUS)0xC000007BL)
```

Вывод: неверный формат подгружаемой библиотеки. Скорее всего, как уже тут ответили в комментах, вы компилируете 32-битное приложение, а библиотека 64-битная.

P.S. Иногда полезно заглядывать в заголовочные файлы, там можно найти ответы на некоторые вопросы;))